failed: failure while getting executionCache: failed to list tasks: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = RBAC: access denied
I am migrating towards kubeflow v2. This is the pipeline I am using (from the tutorial page):
from kfp import dsl
@dsl.component
def say_hello(name: str) -> str:
    hello_text = f'Hello, {name}!'
    print(hello_text)
    return hello_text
 
@dsl.pipeline
def hello_pipeline(recipient: str) -> str:
    hello_task = say_hello(name=recipient)
    return hello_task.output
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile(hello_pipeline, 'pipeline.yaml')

However I get this error:
│ main F1107 17:15:43.212004      21 main.go:79] KFP driver: driver.Container(pipelineName=hello-pipeline, runID=b4d32cdf-bf0f-4adc-bda9-5caf7beced98, task="say-hello", component="comp-say-hello │ │ ", dagExecutionID=29, componentSpec) failed: failure while getting executionCache: failed to list tasks: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = RBAC: access denied                           │ │ main time="2024-11-07T17:15:43.760Z" level=info msg="sub-process exited" argo=true error="<nil>"                                                                                                 │ │ main time="2024-11-07T17:15:43.760Z" level=error msg="cannot save parameter /tmp/outputs/pod-spec-patch" argo=true error="open /tmp/outputs/pod-spec-patch: no such file or directory"           │ │ main time="2024-11-07T17:15:43.760Z" level=error msg="cannot save parameter /tmp/outputs/cached-decision" argo=true error="open /tmp/outputs/cached-decision: no such file or directory"         │ │ main time="2024-11-07T17:15:43.760Z" level=info msg="/tmp/outputs/condition -> /var/run/argo/outputs/parameters//tmp/outputs/condition" argo=true                                                │ │ main Error: exit status 1           
I am not sure what I should be trying to make it work. If anyone has suggestions please let me know.
